# Send an email based on cell values

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't know how to code. I've searched and tried a number of solutions those are provided here by community members. Many ran into error messages (which I wouldn't know how to fix) and the only one that came close seems to work with its own limitation.
So, I am sharing a scenario what I am trying to achieve. I am confident, for you guys it'd be a walk in a park but for me it's like scaling Mt. Everest.

This worksheet consists of multiple sheets (tabs), need to work on just one tab named 'example',

Column B 'Instruments' is there for later reference

Column C 'Close' updates automatically (data is being imported)

Column D 'Watch Level' is defined by me

Column E 'Remarks' gives CCA when the Close is higher than Watch Level, else remains blank (simple if then formula)

The sheet updates once a day after when the market closes.

Let's assume -
After today's close GILB and KSBSL gave CCA as their close exceeded the watch level.

I am looking for a script to send me an email (a single email) when the sheet is updated, containing the information that 'GILB has closed higher than Watch Level, (next line) KMCDB has closed higher than the Watch Level'.. and so on for as many instruments meeting this condition.

Thank you all in advance.

[Example Worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BP2xvDoYrSxMf0V2HTdB7Rj30302wRjaOP20mQ7m3jQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: About your goal of `I am looking for a script to send me an email (a single email) when the sheet is updated, containing the information that 'GILB has closed higher than Watch Level, (next line) KMCDB has closed higher than the Watch Level'`, in this case, can I ask you about the detail of the method of `the sheet is updated`?

Comment: Yep. The solution completely depends on how and by whom the spreadsheet would be updated. It can be done via triggers `onEdit()` or `onChange()`, or via time driven triggers (say, check the sheet every day at 20:00) or via custom menu command, etc.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, the column Close will be updated with data imported from a website using 'importhtml', it is updated everyday as the stock closes different daily when there is a trade and column Watch Level is updated by me manually after I analyze the stock, it is done every once in a while. Thanks.